# Qt Multiple Async While Loops and qApp->processEvents();

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop, qtimer

I am trying to do a project is creating some graphics on window with Qt GUI C++ 5.6.2. 
I have two methods named 'createVerticalSpeedIndicator' and 'createAirSpeedIndicator'. These methods need to create some graphics with a while(1) loop and use qApp->processEvents(); on window and they are doing it perfectly when one of them is working the other one is deactive. But I need to run both of them simultanously and always.

What can I do to run them simultanously and always.

Thank you So much

Comment: Are you currently trying to render both indicators in the same while loop, or two? Are you using an OpenGL widget or built-in widgets? Are you using separate threads for them? Some example pseudo code would be nice. There are too many things that could be going wrong given this description.

Comment: I used threads but I saw some stuckings  I am creating graphics so i thought if show in same loop i could lose smotth. Because i will multply this 15 graphic.I am using built in widget

Comment: What kind of "stuckings" did you experience? Which built-in widget are you using? 15 what, exactly? Post some of your code and a picture of your graphics, please.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to invert the control flow. The `while() { ... processEvents() ... }` is an anti-pattern in asynchronous code, because it assumes that you have locus of control whereas you really don't. You're lucky that you didn't run out of stack since `processEvents` could potentially re-enter the `createXxx` methods.

Here's a complete example of a transformation:

```
// Input
void Class::createVerticalSpeedIndicator() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    doStep(i);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
  }
}
```

```
// Step 1 - factor out state
void Class::createVerticalSpeedIndicator() {
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 100) {
    doStep(i);  
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    i++;
  }
};
```

```
// Step 2 - convert to continuation form
void Class::createVerticalSpeedIndicator() {
  int i = 0;
  auto continuation = [=]() mutable {
    if (!(i < 100))
      return false;
    doStep(i);  
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    i++;
    return true;
  };
  while (continuation());
};
```

```
// Step 3 - execute the continuation asynchronously   
auto Class::createVerticalSpeedIndicator() {
  int i = 0;
  return async(this, [=]() mutable {
    if (!(i < 100))
      return false;
    doStep(i);
    i++; // note the removal of processEvents here
    return true;
  });
};

template <typename F> void async(QObject * parent, F && continuation) {
  auto timer = new QTimer(parent);
  timer->start(0);
  connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [timer, c = std::move(continuation)]{
    if (!c())
      timer->deleteLater();
  });
}
```

At that point you can apply the same transformation to `createAirSpeedIndicator` and start them in the constructor of your class:

```
Class::Class(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) {
  ...
  createVerticalSpeedIndicator();
  createAirSpeedIndicator();
}
```

Both tasks will run asynchronously and pseudo-concurrently within the main thread, i.e. each task will alternatively execute a single step.

Suppose we wanted to chain the tasks, i.e. have a task start only after the previous  one has finished. The modification in the user code can be simple:

```
Class::Class(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) {
  ...
  createVerticalSpeedIndicator()
  >> createAirSpeedIndicator()
  >> someOtherTask();
}
```

The `async` function must now return a class that allows such connections to be made:

```
struct TaskTimer {
  QTimer * timer;
  TaskTimer & operator>>(const TaskTimer & next) {
    next.timer->stop();
    connect(timer, &QObject::destroyed, next.timer, [timer = next.timer]{
      timer->start(0);
    });
    timer = next.timer;
    return *this;
  }
};

template <typename F> TaskTimer async(QObject * parent, F && continuation) {
  TaskTimer task{new QTimer(parent)};
  task.timer->start(0);
  connect(task.timer, &QTimer::timeout, 
          [timer = task.timer, c = std::move(continuation)]{
            if (!c())
              timer->deleteLater();
  });
  return task;
}
```